# Getting more result sets than I wish from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Calling this stored procedure from VB 2008. Trying to fill a `DataGridView` with the results from the `select * from #temptable`. However the stored procedure returns a result set for item and a result set for the last SQL statement. I don't wish to return anything for `@Item`. Only wish to use it in the main statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetItem2]
    @ScanData NVARCHAR(50),
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Begin   
DECLARE @Item char(20)

SELECT i.Item
FROM dbo.Inv_Item i 
WHERE i.Item = @ScanData

Set @RecordCount = @@RowCount

if @@RowCOunt > 0
    Set @Item = @Scandata
Else
    SELECT @Item = Inv_Item.Item
    FROM Inv_UPC 
    INNER JOIN  Inv_Item ON Inv_UPC.Item = Inv_Item.Item
    WHERE upc = @Scandata

    --Set @Item = @Item
    Set @RecordCount = @@RowCount
END

Begin
    SELECT      
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Area, Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Location, 
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item, Inv_Item.[Description],
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.[Level], Inv_item_levels.[levelDescription],
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.GID, 
        Count(Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item) as QTY
    INTO 
        #TempTable
    FROM        
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Inv_Item ON Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item = Inv_Item.Item 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Inv_Item_Levels ON Inv_Item_Location_Detail.[Level] = Inv_Item_Levels.[Level] 
                        AND Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item = Inv_Item_Levels.ItemNumber
    WHERE       
        (Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item = @Item)
    GROUP BY
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Area, Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Location, 
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.Item, Inv_Item_Location_Detail.[Level], 
        Inv_Item_Location_Detail.GID, Inv_Item.[Description],
        Inv_item_levels.[levelDescription]
End 

Select * from #Temptable
```

-- This returns first a value for @Item.
-- Then it returns a result set, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Use `if exists(select ...)` rather than selecting and checking `@@rowcount`. And why are you inserting to the temp table then selecting from it rather than just selecting directly?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should change your first `SELECT` into:

```
DECLARE @Item char(20)

SELECT @Item = i.Item   -- store this value into a variable
FROM dbo.Inv_Item i 
WHERE i.Item = @ScanData
```

That way, the `SELECT` should not be returned as a result set from the stored procedure.